# .hover() mouseleave part not working in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-hover

I am trying to show an overlay `<div>` on image when mouse enters & hide when mouse leaves.

I am using `position:relative;` with `position:absolute;` to do this.My code is working fine in chrome & firefox but in IE 9(i have only this one,so not sure about other versions) it shows overlay image when mouse enter on image but it doesn't remove it when mouse leave the image.

So basically the second part of the `.hove()` not executing.

Here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/AYaJn/.

**HTML**

```
<img id="testimage" src="http://www.dothetest.co.uk/images/do-test.gif" >
```

**CSS**

```
img#testimage{
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$("img#testimage").hover(function(event){
    $(this).wrap("<div id='testdiv'></div>");
    $("#testdiv").css("position","relative");
    var imageWrapperInner="<div class='imageWrapperInnerDiv' style='position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;background-color:#000;width:100%;height:30px;display:none;'></div>";
    $("#testdiv").append(imageWrapperInner);     
     $(".imageWrapperInnerDiv").slideDown("fast");                
},function(event){
    $(".imageWrapperInnerDiv").remove();
    $(this).unwrap();
});

});
```

Comment: Wrapping and unwrapping an element on every mouseenter / leave seems like a generally bad idea, and it's also the cause of the issue with IE, wrapping the element that has the event handler bound with another element etc.

Comment: @adeneo thanks a ton...it worked :)...Can you please post it as an answer so i can mark it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping and unwrapping an element on every mouseenter / leave seems like a generally bad idea, and it's also the cause of the issue with IE, wrapping the element that has the event handler bound with another element etc. Try something like this :

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("#testimage").on({
        mouseenter: function(event){
            var imageWrapperInner = $('<div />', {'class': 'imageWrapperInnerDiv'});
            $('body').append(imageWrapperInner);
            imageWrapperInner.slideDown("fast")
        },
        mouseleave: function(event){
            $(".imageWrapperInnerDiv").remove();
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/AYaJn/3/)